# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email_verified_at' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel

Hi i am using laravel `v5.5` and am getting the error below when i run this command

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

please advice how i can fix the error :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'email_verified_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into users (name,
>   email,email_verified_at, password, created_at, updated_at) values
>   (Admin Admin, admin@material.com, 2020-02-27 13:17:35, $2y$10$0
>   J3IWuCGVzgfPlP8UgfOK.MjNs2R.m5Jri43SPK3VXSy1NDZHKt4u, 2020-02-27
>   13:17:35, 2020-02-27 13:17:35)

**In Connection.php line 452**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'email_verified_at' in 'field list')

if i am to add new columns to the database using laravel can you assist how i can do it .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.5

Comment: make sure the field `email_verified_at` exists in `users` table. check user table and if you don't find it in add `email_verified_at` field.

Comment: I believe email verification is not available on laravel 5.5. I guess you copied factory file from laravel >= 5.7. You can remove `email_verified_at` field from user factory file or upgrade your laravel to >= 5.7

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us your user migration, factory, and seeder?

Comment: I think @train_fox is correct

Comment: i had to navigate to userstableseeder.php and comment out the missing table so that it would not be inserted

Answer (score 1):

make sure your **User Factory** attributes = your **users table** attributes (that is not signed automatically or Could be Null "Null-able" ) like

In your **UserFactory**

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->name,
        'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
}
```

and in your **users table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a migration. Laravel provide an Authentification system, just use `php artisan make:auth`.

It will generate a migration inside `database/migrations/00xx[...].php`
For apply this migration, **you have to run the command**: `php artisan migrate`

This will create all tables and columns.
Once that is done, you can use the Authentification system.

---

If you want to create your own migration (for adding a new column, for example), you can run: `php artisan make:migration add_address_to_users_table` (to add a column `address` in `users` table).

This will create a new folder inside of `database/migrations` and you just have to edit it using this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to fix this problem

As they mention in the comment section you use laravel `v5.5` and get a seeder file from higher version that has this new column `email_verified_at`

**First way**

remove from your seeder file any seeding for the column called `email_verified_at`

**Second way**

In your `users` migration file edit it to be like this one

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            ...........
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            ...........
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

> According to your laravel version i recommend you to use the first way is to delete the `email_verified_at` from your seeder because it's functionallty not suportted in laravel `v5.5` and lower

Answer (score 0):

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'profile_photo_path' in 'field list'

In Laravel 10, you just need to go to your database, users table, and then add the field `profile_photo_path` in the users table, then refresh your application.

Also, make sure to to change the `APP_URL`, from `APP_URL=http://localhost` to `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000`. link your storage with this command: `php artisan storage:link`.